# Как сделать в Google таблицы взаимозависимые ячейки?

Tags: excel, google-spreadsheet, google-docs

Можно ли в google таблицах сделать ячейки с одинаковым содержимым?

Т.е. в ячейке А1 написано "банан", в ячейке b2 тоже самое, если мы меняем в ячейке b2 слово на "апельсин", то и в ячейка А1 значение меняется. И наоборот.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это невозможно сделать посредством табличных функций. Но можно посредством [скрипта](https://www.google.com/script/start/), например:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var cells1 = ["A1", "C3", "A6"];  
  var cells2 = ["B2", "D1", "E4"];
  var value = (typeof e.value == 'object' ? "" : e.value);
  var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  var cell = e.range.getA1Notation();
  var k = cells1.indexOf(cell);
  if (k != -1) {
    sheet.getRange(cells2[k]).setValue(value);
  }
  k = cells2.indexOf(cell);
  if (k != -1) {
    sheet.getRange(cells1[k]).setValue(value);
  }
}
```

Здесь строки

```
  var cells1 = ["A1", "C3", "A6"];  
  var cells2 = ["B2", "D1", "E4"];
```

означают зависимости A1<->B2, C3<->D1, A6<->E4.

Скрипт запускается после каждого редактирования таблицы (это обеспечивает название функции onEdit), сравнивает адрес изменённой ячейки с записанными выше, и осуществляет замену в связанной с ней ячейке.